# Sequence of seed-(looking for an specific result)

Tags: r, loops, seed

How can I change the seed so that it gives me the result that I am looking for and when the match is found how can I get the number of the seed?

the code:

```
set.seed(0)
delta_S<- rep(0,10)
S<- rep(100,10)  
epsilon<- rep(0,10)

  for(i in 1:10){
  epsilon[i]=rnorm(1,0,1)
  delta_S[i]=0.15*(1/52)*S[i]+0.3*(sqrt(1/52))*epsilon[i]*S[i]
  S[i+1]=S[i]+delta_S[i]
 }
  S
  S[11]
```

The result that I am looking for S[11] is 111.54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop

```
S = rep(0, 100)
j = 0

# You can vary digits in order to obtain more precision if you wish
while(round(S[11], digits=2) != 111.54){

  j = j + 1
  set.seed(j)
  delta_S<- rep(0,10)
  S <- rep(100,10)  
  epsilon<- rep(0,10)

  for(i in 1:10){
    epsilon[i]=rnorm(1,0,1)
    delta_S[i]=0.15*(1/52)*S[i]+0.3*(sqrt(1/52))*epsilon[i]*S[i]
    S[i+1]=S[i]+delta_S[i]
  }

}

> j
535

> S
[1] 100.0000  94.6090 103.9302 104.7556 103.1598 105.6781 106.1706 109.8297 109.4760 107.2198 111.5372

> S[11]
111.5372
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time in answering my question. Now I'm able to compare two different approaches. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Delator: You're welcome, glad I was able to help. If you're looking for a more accurate value, change the accuracy in the round condition. If you change the condition to digits=3, a seed of 19256 will give you S[11] = 111.5401 and if you set condition of digits=4, a seed of 1682132 will give you S[11] = 111.54

Comment: @Deltaor I ran the loop with 100,000 seeds and `set.seed(19256)` gives S[11]=111.540095839911

Comment: thanks a lot !!.  I was about to do it, but this was with the code you post or the code of Nishan. I'm confused since its the first time I use this site.

Comment: @Deltaor, I think you should use the code that you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this brute force approach. Keep in mind, this is not efficient, but it does the trick. Basically, you want to loop through seed numbers and print the seeds that give S[11] equal to 111.54. I rounded the result to 2 decimals. In 10,000 seeds, I found two that give S[11] equal to 111.54: 535 and 1937.

```
for (seed_number in 1:10000){
    set.seed(seed_number)
  for(i in 1:10){
    epsilon[i]=rnorm(1,0,1)
    delta_S[i]=0.15*(1/52)*S[i]+0.3*(sqrt(1/52))*epsilon[i]*S[i]
    S[i+1]=S[i]+delta_S[i]
  }
  if(round(S[11],2)==111.54) print(paste("seed is",seed_number))
}

[1] "seed is 535"
[1] "seed is 1937"
```

Using you code, you can verify that `set.seed(535)` will result in S[11] = 111.5372. The same is true for `set.seed(1937)`

```
set.seed(535)
delta_S<- rep(0,10)
S<- rep(100,10)  
epsilon<- rep(0,10)

for(i in 1:10){
  epsilon[i]=rnorm(1,0,1)
  delta_S[i]=0.15*(1/52)*S[i]+0.3*(sqrt(1/52))*epsilon[i]*S[i]
  S[i+1]=S[i]+delta_S[i]
}
S[11]
#[1] 111.5372
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. This is not only helpful for this code but for many more.  I will run this code with a higher seed_number since I'm looking a closer value. thanks again.

Comment: @Deltaor Good. Do not forget to tick your favorite solution so other SO users know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre Laopointe provided good approach to this problem but notice you got 2 answers which is logical because:

```
set.seed(535)
for(i in 1:10){
+   epsilon[i]=rnorm(1,0,1)
+   delta_S[i]=0.15*(1/52)*S[i]+0.3*(sqrt(1/52))*epsilon[i]*S[i]
+   S[i+1]=S[i]+delta_S[i]
+ }
> print(S[11])
[1] 111.5372
> set.seed(1937)
> for(i in 1:10){
+   epsilon[i]=rnorm(1,0,1)
+   delta_S[i]=0.15*(1/52)*S[i]+0.3*(sqrt(1/52))*epsilon[i]*S[i]
+   S[i+1]=S[i]+delta_S[i]
+ }
> print(S[11])
[1] 111.5388
```

You have 10 times random epsilon[i] and I don't know if you need this information but what important is that they differ in each option

```
> set.seed(535)
> rnorm(10,0,1)
 [1] -1.3651733  2.2988608  0.1215605 -0.4354961  0.5174488  0.0426911  0.7590733 -0.1467427 -0.5647193  0.8985600
> set.seed(1937)
> rnorm(10,0,1)
 [1] -0.780397161 -1.862636176  1.900480228  0.999418781  0.492969410 -0.005050631 -0.130317961  0.140431618  0.621808733
[10]  0.767121606
```

And so it doesn't mean that the seed you're given will give the same results with other seed in different circuimstances.